# How to add FPDF totals to the last row of tables?

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array, fpdf

I have a set of tables categorized by their source e.g: 
"Client", "Stock", "Floorstock". 
They look like this:

[image: List of Floor Stock orders]

Each contain lists of prices, which need to be added up and totaled on the last row of the tables.

I'm having problems linking a "totals" array to the "tables" array - specifically displaying each total at the end of each table

So far, the totals of each table are generated in another function, where `sourceTotals` is an instance array:

```
public function setSourceTotalsArray($data)
{
    $this->sourceTotals = $data["source_totals"];
    return $this->sourceTotals;
}
```

This returns an array that looks like this:

```
array(4) { ["Floorstock"]=> int(0) ["Stock"]=> int(0) ["Client"]=> float(32.18)  }
```

Here's where I define my `$pdf` object:

```
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
$data = json_decode($_POST["printData"],true);
$pdf = new PDF();
// Column headings
$month = $pdf->getMonth($data['month']);
$year = $data['year'];
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',10);
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf>title(array('month'=>$month,'year'=>$year,'showroom'=>ucfirst($data['showroom_name'])));
$pdf->tableBody($data);

if(!empty($data["order_detail"])){
    $customerOrders = array();
    $stockOrders = array();
    $floorstockOrders = array();
    $otherOrders = array();

    foreach($data["order_detail"] as $o){
        switch($o["orderSource"]){
            case 'Client':
                $customerOrders[] = $o;
                break;
            case 'Stock':
                $stockOrders[] = $o;
                break;
            case 'Floorstock':
                $floorstockOrders[] = $o;
                break;

            default:
                $otherOrders[] = $o;
                break;
        }
    }

    if (!empty($customerOrders)) {
        $pdf->orderDetail($customerOrders, $data['currency'], 'Client');
    }

    if (!empty($stockOrders)) {
        $pdf->orderDetail($stockOrders, $data['currency'], 'Stock');
    }

    if (!empty($floorstockOrders)) {
        $pdf->orderDetail($floorstockOrders, $data['currency'], 'Floor Stock');
    }

    if (!empty($otherOrders)) {
        $pdf->orderDetail($otherOrders, $data['currency'], 'Client');
    }
}
$pdf->Output();
```

The `orderDetail` function is what structures the table within the `$pdf` object so that the table has cells that correspond to the correct column name:

```
function orderDetail($data,$currencyShortCode, $type){
    $this->orderType = $type;
    list($currencySymbol, $w_symbol, $cellHight) = $this->getOrderDetailHeader($currencyShortCode, $type);

    foreach ($data as $d){
        $commaValue = $this->addComma((float)$d['value']);
        $this->Cell(15,$cellHight,$d['order_no'],'LTB',0,'L');
        $this->Cell(20,$cellHight,substr($d['customer'],0,13),'TB',0,'L');
        $this->Cell(20,$cellHight,substr($d['company'],0,13),'TB',0,'L');
        $this->Cell(20,$cellHight,substr($d['ref'],0,13),'TB',0,'L');           
        $this->Cell(2,$cellHight,'','TB',0,'R');
        $this->Cell($w_symbol,$cellHight,$currencySymbol,'TB',0,'R');
        $this->Cell(16-$w_symbol,$cellHight,$commaValue,'TB',0,'R');
        $this->Cell(2,$cellHight,'','TB',0,'R');
        $this->Cell(10,$cellHight,$d['cat'],'TB',0,'L');
        $this->Cell(84,$cellHight,$d['description'],'RTB',0,'L');
        $this->Ln($cellHight);
    }
    //BOTTOM TOTAL
    $this->Cell(13,$cellHight,'TOTAL','LRTB',0,'L');
    $this->Cell(22,$cellHight,'','TB',0,'L');
    $this->Cell(20,$cellHight,'','TB',0,'L');
    $this->Cell(20,$cellHight,'','TB',0,'L');
    $this->Cell(4,$cellHight,$currencySymbol,'TB',0,'R');
    $this->Cell(14,$cellHight,$this->setSourceTotalsArray($data),'TB',0,'R'); //HERE
    $this->Cell(2,$cellHight,'','TB',0,'R');
    $this->Cell(10,$cellHight,'','TB',0,'L');
    $this->Cell(84,$cellHight,'','RTB',0,'L');
}
```

I'm just not sure how to pass `setSourceTotalsArray` into `orderDetail`, as my current attempt only returns `null`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `setSourceTotalsArray` method doesn't really do anything, so if it returns `null` that means `$data` does not have a `source_totals` node. (Suggestion/sidenote: set [error reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting) to `E_ALL` so PHP will warn you about this; then for live environments turn `display_errors` off and enable `log_errors` so you'll see the errors in the log but your visitors won't see them on the screen.)
The reason `source_totals` does not exist in `$data` is that the $data`variable inside`orderDetail`is only a subset of`$data` in the full script.

What I would do is add a `$total` argument to `orderDetail`. You the get something like this:

```
function orderDetail($data,$currencyShortCode, $type, $total) {
    ...
    $this->Cell(14,$cellHight, $total,'TB',0,'R'); //HERE
    ...
}
```

And

```
if (!empty($customerOrders)) {
    $pdf->orderDetail($customerOrders, $data['currency'], 'Client', $data['source_totals']['Client']);
}
// Also add the 4th argument for stock orders, floor orders and others.
```

Answer (score 2):

Another fantastic way to generate PDF is simply using the wkhtmltopdf binary.

if you already have a report, that generates html, you can use output buffering to generate html and then convert to pdf, it can run on most environments and you can control exactly the output you want, just like WebKit (Chrome, Safari, etc.) do it, using a familiar language (HTML).

HTH.